# Save find -exec output to text file

Tags: shell, find, io-redirection, ffmpeg

I have a set of videos in the folder. I would like to get the info about this videos using `ffmpeg -i` command and save the output to file.

So I wrote the line:

`find . -type f -exec ffmpeg -i {} \; > log.txt`

But surprisingly, the log is empty! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what might be happening here is that `ffmpeg` is sending its output to `stderr`, in which case what you want is just:

```
find . -type f -exec ffmpeg -i {} \; 2>log.txt
```

I don't have `ffmpeg` in my distro to test with, but this has been verified with `avconv` from `libav` (should still be the same in this respect).

Answer (score 0):

set the output inside the exec

```
find . -type f -exec ffmpeg -i {} \; > log.txt

breno@stormtrooper:/tmp$ find . -type f -exec ls {} >> /tmp/test.log \;
find: `./pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n`: Permission denied
breno@stormtrooper:/tmp$ ls
hsperfdata_breno  pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n  ssh-SLDpHf9PBb5g  t2  test.log
breno@stormtrooper:/tmp$ cat test.log 
./.X0-lock
./.t2.swp
./hsperfdata_breno/3692
./test.log
./.wine-1000/server-801-8a0557/lock
./t2
```

Comment: `find . -type f -exec ls {} >> /tmp/test.log \;` is exactly the same as `find . -type f -exec ls {} \; >> /tmp/test.log`. It's a simple command, the redirection can be anywhere on the line.