# Correct location for piping and redirecting output in find -exec?

Tags: shell, find, freebsd, io-redirection

I'm using `find` with the `-exec` option in console, on FreeBSD (for example, `find . -exec sha1 {} \;`).

1. How do I correctly place (and if needed, escape) redirect and other execution control symbols that could syntactically apply to either of the exec command or the find command, such as > >> | and &, where I might want the symbol to apply to the `find` or the `exec` commands on different occasions?
2. On the same theme, what is the syntax if I want to use `tee` to view the output of the -exec commands on the console (to watch progress) and also appended to a file (for later use)?

*(I know shells vary but hopefully the most used shells such as sh/csh are quite similar?)*

**Update:**

In part, I want to learn if nested `find -exec` can be done without scripting, as a simple command. Here is the use-case that prompted the questio :

- outer `find`: find all subdirs matching DIR_MATCH_TEXT in `DIR1`
- inner `find`: for each matching subdir found in the outer loop (call it DIR2), execute the command
  `find DIR2 -name "FILE_MATCH_TEXT" -exec sha1 {} \; >> DIR1/DIR2_hashes.txt`

The aim being to create a set of files, one for each matching subdir, containing the output of some `find -exec` action on that subdir.

By this I mean that, if `/backups` contains `/jan2017` and `/feb2017`, the result will be two files at `/backups/jan2017_hashes.txt` and `/backups/feb2017_hashes.txt`, with `jan2017_hashes.txt` containing the output from `sha1` for (say) all .pdf files in `/backups/jan2017`, and `feb2017_hashes.txt` containing the output from `sha1` for all .pdf files in `/backups/feb2017`.

From replies so far I gather the outer `find` would have to use a shell call as the argument to `-exec`?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find

Comment: Duplicate question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111520/save-find-exec-output-to-text-file?rq=1 .  You can just do that at the end.  If, for some reason, that doesn't correspond to what you're expecting, then try adding both `stdout` AND `stderr` output to the specified location for redirection.

Comment: These seem to conflict, which is what confuses me. The first suggests that redirect just doesn't work inside exec (_"A shell command can include redirection and piping; -exec cannot (although the whole find can be redirected)"_), the second says it works anywhere inside or out (_"set the output inside the exec "_ and _"-exec ls {} >> /tmp/test.log \;"_). That's part of what confuses me.

Comment: @Stilez In the second case, you may move the redirection to the end of the command. It is not part of `-exec` nor of the options to `find`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356118/how-is-this-command-legal-file1-file2-cat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I/O redirection and piping are functions of shells (e.g., bash).  Looking at the source code of the `find` command (https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), the `-exec` option forks and directly execs the given command, it does not send it though any shell.  Given that, without help, you cannot include piping and redirection in the argument to `find`.

You can, however, have `find` invoke a shell and have that shell in turn invoke your command.  When running the same through a shell, you have access to the I/O redirection operations exposed by the shell.  Consider, for example:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'ls -l "$1" >> /tmp/result' find-sh {} \;
```

That will run `ls -l` on each file found by `find` (the shell refers to that file in this context as `$0`) and redirect the output to `/tmp/result`.  Note that I used `>>` instead of `>`.  Here, find is invoking a shell for each file, so `>` will result in each result overwriting the previous -- you'll end up with a file that contains only the output from the last command.

Pipes will work as well, with the same caveat of "one exec per file".

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'ls -l "$1" | grep something' find-sh {} \;
```

All that said, it's not immediately clear to me why you'd want to apply redirection within the context of the `-exec`, or what it would buy you over performing the redirection on the output of find itself.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. The question you pose at the end is also good, its making me think, too!

Comment: Updated question to explain the use-case. Is it possible?

Comment: I use this to count the files in a set of directories
`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'echo -n "$0 ";find $0 -name "*.txt" | wc -l' {} \; | sort`

Comment: Two things: 1) It's a little confusing when you give a dummy argument to bash, `find-sh`, especially without explanation. Consider omitting it, and using `$0` inside your bash command instead. 2) As an example of why one wants this, consider that one `find` command may have several conditional `-exec` paths, of which only one needs piping, or several need different kinds of piping. E.g. I have one find command that `mkdir`s all dirs found, pipes `mediainfo` output from media files, and `ln -s`s remaining files.